# How to run Xilinx ISim simulater faster?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, simulation, xilinx

I have started to write serious test benches with lots of loops which have inner loops to check all the possible input conditions of a design.

Some of the test benches takes hour to finish. I am just wondering how people run these test benches faster? Do they use supercomputers?

Comment: No direct experience, so comment rather than answer. 'Hardware in the loop' is a general term. Many simulation vendors support connecting to FPGA boards, and moving some or all of the simulation to hardware. A JIT supercomputer basically!

Answer (score 2):

You may find another simulator like [ghdl (open source)](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl) is faster than ISIM for many designs, even though there is less (no) development money available for optimising its performance.

If you structure your testbenches as independent tests, as favoured by [Vunit (a VHDL unit testing framework)](http://vunit.github.io/installing.html), you can run multiple instances of ghdl (or commercial simulation tools like Modelsim if you can afford enough licenses) in parallel, by [simply setting a command line option](http://vunit.github.io/posts/2015_12_15_free_and_open_source_verification_with_vunit_and_ghdl/post.html), up to the number of processors in your system.

(This assumes you're using vhdl, you didn't mention any HDL in your post. I don't know the state of simulation tools for verilog)

Comment: I initially used ISim. Then I switched to ModelSim and it is way faster.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice it's you, I know you're using VHDL. For power user testbenching I'd take a good look at Vunit.